# Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract Extended Row Class Not Functioning

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm using the Zend_Db framework, and I've run into a snag. I'm trying to add custom handling to the column naming at the row level, but it's failing to invoke my function for some reason.

I've stripped down the problem to simply try and figure out if the underlying "Row" class is ever even created. From what I can tell, it isn't.

Here's what I've got:

```
// this class functions correctly; I get "table" written to my output
class DHR_Table extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_rowClass = 'DHR_Row';

    function __construct(){
        echo "table";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

// this class never gets called, at least not that is evident from the constructor echo
class DHR_Row extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
    protected $inflector = null;

    function __construct(){
        echo "row";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

// this is the actual implementation class that uses these two:
class Application_Model_DbTable_Applicants extends DHR_Table
{
    protected $_name = 'applicants';
}
```

My output includes some data (excluded from this post, but part of the "Applicants" class) and "table", but no "row". Any ideas why this might be happening? Version 1.11.11 of the Zend framework.

[Edit]
Here's the usage:

```
class ApplicantsController extends DHR_RestController
{    
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $applicants = new Application_Model_DbTable_Applicants();
        $result = $applicants->fetchAll();
        $this->success($result);
    }
    protected function success($data, $code = 200)
    {
            if(is_a($data, 'Zend_Db_Table_Rowset')){
                    // we could do some pagination work here
                    $data = $data->toArray();
            }
            $this->setResponseCode($code)->appendBody(Zend_Json::encode(array(
                    'success'=>true,
                    'data' => $data
            )));
    }
}
```

I would expect to at least have some method on the row class invoked when returning the serialized results...

**[Update]**
If I use "fetchRow" everything works as expected; fetchAll simply does't do the conversion to the underlying object type.

Comment: Side note: if I change $_rowClass to something invalid, I do get an error, so it *is* at least loading up the script; but why would my echo statement not show?

Comment: How do you use the class? When you expect that the Row constructor should be executed?

Comment: Well, just few ideas: you can use debugger (xcode etc.) and step through the execution to see how it works inside and why your function is not invoked. You can also use `die('row');` instead of the `echo` to be sure that the function is not executed. Just guessing - but the row class will only be created when the Rowset is not empty.  You also can try `var_dump($result);` to see what of consist the returned Rowset.

Comment: Yeah; I've got 1 record, and die('row'); does't change anything. Frustrating :)

Comment: I think this is lazy loaded and won't be called until it's needed. Call the __constructor and see what happens.

Comment: ok I was wrong just did some experimenting and got this result using the same __construct function as @jvenema.  table  row
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAdapter() on a non-object in C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Db\Table\Row\Abstract.php on line 925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just looking at the code for the *row/abstract* class.
Try setting a value for $_tableClass.
    `$_tableClass = 'DHR_Table';`

I'm afraid that won't work as it looks like *Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php* is going to look for a table definition no matter what, so the level of abstraction you seem to be after may not be possible without further extending.

```
//excerpt from __construct Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php

public function __construct(array $config = array())
    {
        if (isset($config['table']) && $config['table'] instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            $this->_table = $config['table'];
            $this->_tableClass = get_class($this->_table);
        } elseif ($this->_tableClass !== null) {
            $this->_table = $this->_getTableFromString($this->_tableClass);
        }
 // cont...
 // Retrieve primary keys from table schema
        if (($table = $this->_getTable())) {
            $info = $table->info();
            $this->_primary = (array) $info['primary'];
        }

        $this->init();
```

Comment: For further visitors - you have to do a ton of additional extending, all the base classes pretty much that are used by Zend DB. I had about 6 or 7 subclasses defined before  I tossed it out and used a simpler framework (phpactiverecord) to accomplish what I needed.